# Fetch wind in yahoo weather xml in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

Yahoo Weather has changed its XML address for weather queries.

Previously it was something like this : 
`http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/`

And now it has become : 
`https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid=`

So, in my AS3, I was fetching the wind and the wind direction, but now it doesn't seems to work with the new link. For example: with this link below we can query an XML for the wind speed and direction :

`https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid=1049640%20AND%20u=%22f%22`

From the returned XML, the required entry looks like : `<yweather:wind speed="3" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" direction="80" chill="80"/>`

My AS3 code is :

```
var url:String;
url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid=1049640 AND u="f"';
var yahooWeatherXML:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url)
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(yahooWeatherXML);
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,weatherLoaded);



        function weatherLoaded(e:Event):void{
    xml = new XML(e.target.data);
    var cityTxt = xml.channel.yweather::location.@city;
    var windD = xml.channel.yweather::wind.@direction;

var windTxt = "Wind: "+ (Math.round(xml.channel.yweather::wind.@speed/1.852)+"nd");


urlLoader.load(yahooWeatherXML);

    accueil.info_txt.text = windTxt +" "+windDirectionTxt;
urlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,weatherLoaded);
 }
```

Any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: When you paste your example URL into your browser, you will get the XML that gets returned by the API. From the looks of it, you simply didn't change your code, but the XML is different. For example I see that the xml has a tag called `results` which holds the entire rest of the XML, yet I see no mention of `results` in your code. `xml.channel.yweather` should be something like `xml.results.channel.yweather`

Comment: Consider what @DodgerThud said. Also just minor technical issues... **(1)** Make sure `url = ` looks like how it does in browser address bar (no spaces instead use `%20`). **(2)** Is your app running from a website address that begins with `https://`? If not, then it might be an issue of mixing your `http` vs their `https` content together in one app. I wouldnt think so for XML (text) but you never know...

Comment: Thx for the answers. I've managed to correct my code. Last question. Do you know how can I fetch the "Sunny" word in this line ?`<yweather:condition xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" text="Sunny" temp="78" date="Thu, 21 Apr 2016 07:46 AM NCT" code="32"/>`   I've tried : `var weatherCondition = xml.results.channel.yweather::condition.@text;` but it's not working